# Render transperent shadows in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am trying to render an animation in cycles without the background. However, every time I have it render, the background still shows up.

I used the compositor to add a background image so I can animate the object around the background. I set the output to RGBA and set the film to transparent.

Now I want to use it in After effects and I simply want to export/render it without the background and make it transparent.  How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.. Are you asking how to setup the composite nodes so there is no background image, only transparency?

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to have a background image but have it transparent when doing a render pass

Comment: You mean have the color information, but completely transparent?

Comment: http://vimeo.com/71859089, around 6:00. he has the background but he renders it in a way that the photo is not there and is transparent or empty. The problem is all the tutorials like these use internal render

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but if I understand correctly, you can make the background image color information remain in the image while still making it completely transparent.

This can be done with the *Set alpha* node, with an *Alpha* of `0`:

[image]

However, in the video you linked to the scene is rendered without any information about the background image at all.

Here is a setup that will do this:

[image]

Comment: When I render I don't want the background image.

Comment: @user2883800 How's this?

Comment: When I render it the background is all white except the objects

Comment: @user2883800 Hmm.. Is *Transparent* still enabled in *Render > Film*? Is the *ColorRamp* stop set to transparent? If those are correct, could you upload the .blend?

Comment: nevermind it works now, I didn't make the colorRamp transparent

Answer (score 2):

You can render an image with a transparent background without compositing.

For cycles you enable a transparent background in the Film panel -

[image]

The same result can be achieved in Blender internal under Shading by choosing transparent instead of Sky for Alpha -

[image]

Comment: The OP already enabled *Transparent* (from the question: "I set the output to RGBA and set the film to transparent"), I think he/she wants to know how to include the shadows from the other renderlayer shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes for BI this will give you what you want as you can set shadow only for material but cycles you have to composite shadows.

Comment: Right. Then if I understand it, this answer does not answer the question?

Comment: I found a video that solve the problem but part of the solution was making the color in ColorRamp transparent.