# Transparent Plane that receives shadow and light emitted by object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light, transparency

I can make a plane to be transparent and only show the shadow of an object with the *Shadow only* option in the *Shadow* category of the material. That is useful for making 2D graphics with transparent shadow.
Is it possible to make the plane show the shadow and the light emitted by my object?
Like in this screenshot, only the background plane should be transparent:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How is your object emitting light? Can we see some screenshots?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/render-shadow-on-transparent-background-on-blender-render/14900#14900

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/render-transperent-shadows-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3095/shadowless-render-pass

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: I am using Bl. The links above use cycles, so I am currently trying to use that. So far I did not get it to work. Is there a way to do that with Bl?