# Setting an object to render transparent with shadows

Tags: texturing

I'm composting a blender scene into live footage. I have objects interacting with my "ground." what I want to do is set up the ground to render out transparent so that we can't see it in the composite video, but the objects interacting with the ground still need shadows. How can I set this up?

Comment: see if [this is what you want](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14900/5113) also [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5160/5113)

Comment: This  tut may be useful for U: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_B2H_jnaoU