# Cycles: compositing alpha channel

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have rendered an object using hdri and lamp lights.
Using render layers i want to have object and shadows only.
I show you my nodes. 
I need to know how to transform white pixels to alpha channel using nodes.
[image]

Comment: No it is not. I want to know how to do it using render layers in order to have an alpha channel. Just i need to transform white pixel to alpha.

Comment: Jerryno, I need a pgn image in order to use it as image web site. Just, the object and shadow only.

Comment: You cannot transform white to alpha, you can transform black pixels to alpha but that won't give you shadow. You can transform white pixels for CMYK mode into alpha.

Comment: related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/render-transperent-shadows-in-cycles

Comment: @jagoji3d That question has the answers you want, you just need to output the transparent image and not add it onto the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to enable a **shadow pass**, invert the colors and use that as alpha using a **Set Alpha** node.

[image]

The Dilate/Erode will help with the antialiasing of the shadow pass.

**EDIT**

Now... if you hate the previous option and absolutely want to use the layers you have set up, you can try this:

From the background layer you can indeed subtract the shadow layer, creating a black and white image that holds the shadow information only. But use difference instead of subtract (also, you don't need the invert node because you can invert the image with the curves node, but you do need to get rid of the color information). Next, combine that image with the alpha channel of the sphere, and use the resulting image as alpha channel on the mix of the shadow and the sphere...

[image]